# Is there a way to animate fixed position images with jQuery animate function?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I have some social icon links at the side of my web page and they are positions using CSS `position:fixed` so that they don't move when the rest of the page is scrolled.

The icon images are 90px wide and what I've also done is position them mostly off-screen so that only 15px of them are visible until mouseover - then the rest of them appear.  I accomplish this using CSS and the `.hover` attribute but they just 'pop' out by doing it this way.

I'd like to have smoothy slide out and it seems to me the best way to do this would be to use the jquery `animate` function however I have absolutely no idea how to do it.

Here's the CSS I'm currently using to shift the images ....

```
.floater-side-fb {
    position:fixed;
    bottom: 600px;
    right:-70px;
}
.floater-side-fb a:hover{
    position:fixed;
    bottom: 600px;
    right: -5px;
}
```

and the html ...

```
<div class="floater-side-fb">
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank"><img src="images/facebook-icon.png" /></a>
</div>
```

Comment: If you want to use CSS3, you could just add the appropriate `transition` properties in the `.floater-side-fb` rule; set `transition`, `-webkit-transition`, `-moz-transition`, `-o-transition` and `-khtml-transition` to `right 0.5s ease-in-out` where `0.5s` is the duration. You might prefer it, though it only works in Safari, Chrome, and Firefox 4 (in terms of major browsers) currently. The reason I suggest it instead is because it allows you to keep `:hover` and have very clean code, plus great easing options and efficiency (browser code is faster than JavaScript).

Comment: I think you shouldn't have a fixed element inside another fixed element

Comment: @minitech: Until all the major browsers support features, it is hard to advocate their use.  Websites rarely have the luxury of working for "some" of the market; if you have to code an alternative, might as well just use it in the first place.

Comment: Well, progressive enhancement is a fundamental design principle - why would anyone try to implement `position: fixed` for IE6, for example - so CSS3 is still viable. A small animation isn't a matter of working or not working for "some" of the market. The website will work without a small animation, it will just be nicer for people with capable browsers.

Comment: @Minitech - thinki I'll forget jQuery and go with this solution. Maybe it's because I'm more proficient when it comes to CSS - I dunno - but having tested this I think it's awesome and for those browsers that don't support it yet ... they still accept what CSS they can so they'll be left with the not-so-fancy pop-out animation which is still good because the functionality remains. Thank you for this tip bro - it's really very much appreciated ;)

Comment: @minitech: As long as the other browsers display something acceptable, then yes.  If he can still get the hover effect to work in this case, fine.  In many cases you might have broken functionality without JS to cope with the missing feature. [BTW, when you respond to someone, you need to put their name with an (at) symbol in front of it to notify them.  Stumbled on this response by chance.]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) documentation.

```
$('.floater-side-fb').hover(function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({ 'right': '-5px' }, 'slow', 'linear');
}, function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({ 'right': '-70px' }, 'slow', 'linear');
});
```

NB. You'll want to remove that `:hover` class in the CSS first.